# (SQL) Can not execute variable as name[ ' x ' ]

Tags: python, mysql, string

I'm try to get 3 data from one function. `X,Y,Z` data from `get_gyro_data()` function. When i'm try to execute these datas in order to insert tab ***TAB_MPU*** and columns **GX,GY,GZ** . I use i2c for gettin data from MPU6050

```
  math functions 
  math functions
  .
  .
  .
  x= x/scaler
  y= y/scaler
  z=z/scaler
  return {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}

def get_all_data(self):
  gyro = get_gyro_data()
```

After get gyro data im tryin to write database like ;

```
while True :
    mpu = MPU6050(0x68) //my sensor
    gyro_data = mpu.get_gyro_data()
    print(gyro_data['x'])
    print(gyro_data['y'])
    print(gyro_data['z'])
    Time = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    Date = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    print (Time + " - " + Date)
    sql = ("""INSERT INTO `TAB_TEMP` (`Date`,`Time`,`JX`,`JY`,`JZ`,`IX`,`IY`,`IZ`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""(Date,Time,accel_data['x'],accel_data['y'],accel_data['z'],gyro_data['x'],gyro_data['y'],gyro_data['z'])) 
    cursor.execute(sql)  // execute sql command
```

When i debug program, I got exception TypeError : 'str' object is not callable at `sql= (""" INSERT .... )` line

Comment: Like the exception says, youre trying to call a `str` object; `"""..."""()` is just that. Instead pass the SQL string as the 1st and the argument tuple as the 2nd argument to `execute()`. And if someone tells you to use the `%` string formatting operator, ignore them.

Comment: Sorry, i lost my connection cant check here. I wrote like `cusor.execute(sql,args)`. It working Thanks alot!